# How do I set Windows-related file attributes in ruby?

Tags: windows, ruby, file

How do I tell ruby to create files with the attributes `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` and `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`?

Answer (score 3):

You can call Windows functions using the Ruby win32api library. See these [examples](http://www.rubytips.org/2008/05/13/accessing-windows-api-from-ruby-using-win32api-library/). It's painful, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I grepped Ruby 1.8.7 source and did not find any mention of those attributes, so I'm thinking that you get to fix it and build from source...

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of it's Unix roots, Ruby doesn't (yet) allow that. You can probably obtain the result you want with:

```
require 'tempfile'
Tempfile.new "my_temp_file" do |f|
  #...
end
```